# Javascript childNodes lists more than the number of child elements

Tags: javascript

I'm just learning javascript but this is very confusing to me.

I am trying to learn how the childNodes property works. I am using it on a div with three h1 tags in it and nothing else, yet it is returning 7 child nodes. Why is this?

https://jsfiddle.net/xyzL65Lv/

html:

```
<head>
<title>Learn Javascript</title>
</head>

<body>

<div>
    <h1 id="title">one</h1>
    <h1 id="title2">two</h1>
    <h1 id="title3">three</h1>
</div>

</body>
```

javascript:

```
parent = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
children = parent[0].childNodes;
for(var i=0; i<children.length; i++){
    document.write("#" + i + " " + children[i].innerHTML + "<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.childNodes` includes all nodes of a parent element, including text nodes

Comment: What other nodes are in the div? I don't get it. It's just three h1 tags.

Comment: @asharpdesigner `#textNodes` `children[i].nodeName` https://jsfiddle.net/xyzL65Lv/1/. Comment nodes and processing instruction nodes are also returned by `.childNodes`

Comment: Ah I get it, it counts the blank space before and after each element.

Comment: Technically not "blank space". See https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#text